# switch audio source with jquery and HTML5 audio tag

Tags: jquery, html, audio, html5-audio

I have only found one other solution but it was incomplete so I need help here.

i have the audio set up:

```
<audio id="player" controls="controls">
          <source id="ogg_src" src="lib/audio/barger01.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
          <source id="mp3_src" src="lib/audio/barger01.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
          Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
```

I have a dynamically generated table of links to change the track:

```
<div id="audio_list">
   <a href="#" class="track" data-location="http://www.newoggtrack.ogg">sample</a>
</div>
```

i have this jquery that i have no clue what to do with to change the track

```
$('.track').click(function(){

    load_track = $(this).attr('data-location');//gets me the url of the new track

    change_track(load_track);// function to change the track of the loaded audio player without page refresh preferred...

});
```

i found this function but i am not using it the right way

```
 function change_track(sourceUrl) {

        audio.empty();
        $("#ogg_src").attr("src", sourceUrl).appendTo(audio);
        /****************/
        audio[0].pause();
        audio[0].load();//suspends and restores all audio element
        /****************/
    }

audio = $("<audio>").attr("id", "player")
                        .attr("preload", "auto");
```

Comment: What is your problem? What happens when you try and switch? Do you get an error? And is the code with the `function change()` a direct copy and paste or is it just pieces of code you've pulled out?

Comment: change function is something i found but it does not work. it throws now error

Comment: Post the error then. How do you expect people to help you if they don't know what's wrong?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Your change function should be like this:

```
function change(sourceUrl) {
    var audio = $("#player");      
    $("#ogg_src").attr("src", sourceUrl);
    /****************/
    audio[0].pause();
    audio[0].load();//suspends and restores all audio element

    //audio[0].play(); changed based on Sprachprofi's comment below
    audio[0].oncanplaythrough = audio[0].play();
    /****************/
}
```

The problems were audio.empty() and the audio var.  You were attempting to append an emptied audio tag, and didn't write out the audio tag back to the browser.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It cleared up what i was doind and works like a charm. I hope i awarded the bounty correctly.

Comment: Solved my problem. Seems you have to use the load() method, otherwise the HTML player won't actually load the sound, even if the DOM was updated. thanks!

Comment: Also why not audio[1] or just audio? I wish I knew enough javascript to know a way to get the answer myself. I php I would have done a print_r on audio.

Comment: @David天宇Wong, jQuery returns an array, so this takes the first instance of that array.

Comment: yeah my question was more, what's in the second instance for example ?

Comment: audio[0] is the DOM object rather than the jQuery object. Only the DOM object has a .play() method.

Comment: Note that I ran into problems with this code because often the audio isn't yet fully loaded when play() is called and then it ignores the play() instruction. So I changed that to audio[0].oncanplaythrough = audio[0].play() .

Comment: Merged suggestion from @Sprachprofi, nearly two years later :)

Answer (score 6):

You might also want to rename the function since 'change' is already a function in the jQuery universe.