# how to change the audio source using Javascript

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm doing a personal project using css/Javascript/html
I've encountered a little problem with my audio.
The situation is that I have an audio playing as soon as the 
page loads (that works) but after ones HP turns to 0 I want the audio
to change. What happens is once I get to that situation the audio is cut out.

```
<audio id="myAudio" src="BattleTheme.mp3" type='audio/mp3'></audio>
```

JavaScript code:

```
 function intervalDone(){
   var y=document.getElementById("message");    
   if(h1<=0){
    document.getElementById('att').src="backgrounds/spacertransparent1.png";
    document.getElementById('slaz').src="characters/slayerzach/slayerzach-faintTransparent.png";
    document.getElementById('myAudio').src="BattleWin.mp3";
    y.innerHTML="<center>SlayerZach has fainted, FighterDan13 Wins.</center>";
    document.getElementById("butAtt").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("butItems").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("butRun").disabled = true;
       }
   }
```

Comment: This has already been answered here:

**http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421505/switch-audio-source-with-jquery-and-html5-audio-tag**

Comment: I'm looking for a pure JavaScript answer but thanks anyway...

Comment: Are you using iPads/iPhones by any chance?