# HTML5 audio player. Cannot change the src element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I am trying to dynamically change the value of the src of my HTML audio player and for some reason I can't change it and it stuck on it's placeholder value.
This is my HTML element:

```
    <audio controls preload="none" style="width:480px;">
    <source id="mp3" src="placeholder" type="audio/mp3" />
    </audio>
```

And this is my Javascript:

```
var tempMp3 = "http://www.someurl.org/somefile.mp3";
$("#mp3").attr("src", tempMp3);
```

Anybody knows what silly mistake am i doing here?

Cheers

Comment: You're probably trying to modify the element before the DOM is loaded. Can you show where in the HTML you're putting your javascript?

Comment: I am putting it in the Body, before the HTML

Comment: That's your issue. See @Ethaan's answer for details.

Comment: You can find a great solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9512994/358331

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks ok, maybe like @Nick Dugger says you are trying to change the DOM element when isn't ready yet

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready."
>   jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside
>   $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object
>   Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included
>   inside $( window ).load(function() { ... }) will run once the entire
>   page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

**First option**

Try putting the code inside this [$(document).ready()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var tempMp3 = "http://www.someurl.org/somefile.mp3";
    $("#mp3").attr("src", tempMp3);
});
```

**Second Option**

Another option could be place the `<script>` tag on the end of the `<body>` tag

Comment: Although probably the solution, `$( document ).ready` is often abused. Also, can you explain to OP *why* he needs this?

Comment: For the record, I do not condone the use of `$( document ).ready` and suggest firing javascript at the end of the body.

Comment: This one did the trick but I still have another issue that stems from failing to move this tempMp3 string between 2 functions. Thanks for the help!

Comment: hi @PavelZagalsky if you have another different issue, could you please make another SO Question and up vote this one? since the problem here was solved

Comment: I will do so indeed. Many thanks @Ethaan and everybody who helped

Answer (score 1):

Try a bit of plain JavaScript:

```
var audio=document.getElementById("my_audio_element");
audio.src="source.mp3";
audio.play();
```

This works for me. HTML5 Audio is still sort of shaky and isn't implemented the same across all major browsers. If you're trying to get it to play on mobile, that's even trickier. Your code looks fine to me, though. Hope this helps!

Comment: This code will work if you run it. Downvoter, explain your downvote!

Answer (score -1):

After you change the source, be sure to run the `.load()` function on the audio element to load the change.

Example (assuming the id "audio" is set the audio element):

```
var tempMp3 = "http://www.someurl.org/somefile.mp3";
$("#mp3").attr("src", tempMp3);
$("#audio").load();
$("#audio").play();
```

Comment: Like this: $("#mp3").attr("src", tempMp3).load();?

Comment: Ouch -2 >_< Something wrong with this? Also, had it set wrong before, it's updated now to call load on the audio element instead Pavel.