# Javascript button multiple audio source

Tags: javascript, button, audio

So i am working on a school project and am pretty new to coding. My project is to make a little playlist with javascript, but I only want my project to have one universal button and have multiple audio sources. I want the user to be able to select the song and be able to play it with the button. Any ideas?

Comment: S.O. is more for trouble-shooting a problem in code. I suggest you post this question in something like r/javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [switch audio source with jquery and HTML5 audio tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421505/switch-audio-source-with-jquery-and-html5-audio-tag)

Answer (score 0):

This uses [HtmlAudioElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement), I did not test with the audios, but that's the idea, may help you as a reference to implement your code.

```js
var aux = 1;

function playAudiox() {
  if (aux == 1) {
    console.log("Playing Track 1.");
    var track1 = new Audio('track1.mp3');
    track1.play();
    aux++;
  } else if (aux == 2) {
    console.log("Playing Track 2.");
    var track2 = new Audio('track2.mp3');
    track2.play();
    aux++;
  } else if (aux == 3) {
    console.log("Playing Track 3.");
    var track3 = new Audio('track3.mp3');
    track3.play();
    aux = 1;
  }
}
```

```css
#tracklist {
  height: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.tracks {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 80px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="tracklist">

  <div class="tracks">track1</div>
  <div class="tracks">track2</div>
  <div class="tracks">track3</div>
</div><br>
<button id="universalPlay" onclick="playAudiox()">Universal Play</button>
```

Comment: thanks it plays the audio files in order but not are selectable. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @jackyzeng it's simple to make it selectable, create one parameter in `playAudiox(track)`  and on div click call e,g `playAudiox(divNumber)`